# Why doesn't Cecilia think the police will be suspicious?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-invisible-man-2020

At the end of *The Invisible Man* (2020),

> Adrian seemingly kills himself by cutting his own throat and this activity is recorded on CCTV. 
>  However, we all know it was actually Cecilia using an Invisibility suit.

The movie implies she'll get away with it because there is supposedly incontrovertible evidence that he did it to himself.

But by this point, don't the police know that Invisibility suits exist? I mean she is certainly using it for her own defense which is corroborated by many witnesses at the hospital, the (albeit broken) suit found at James' house, and the raid by the SWAT guys of Adrian's house seems to suggest that she is believed by the authorities.

So why won't the police, when looking at a man looking all smug and satisfied suddenly decide to take a knife and kill himself (possibly looking surprised while he's doing it!) not wonder if it was really someone in an invisibility suit? I'm sure Cecilia leaving the scene after calling 911 will only make them more suspicious.

(I know we never get to see whether they do, but the movie ends implying that she's getting away with it).

Comment: Please use spoiler tags for spoilers. >! prefix will hide the relevant text

Comment: @Tetsujin - I was thinking that, but the entire question is a big spoiler so I thought the text warning would be relevant too... A J 9 seems to disagree...

Comment: I'm keeping my eyes averted from your question body ;) but check what can be read from the main page before anyone opens the question. Make sure you can't see any spoilers there in the few lines of preview that's shown.

Comment: I don't think the police knows about the suit. They take it off the brother in James's house and probably destroy it. They can pretend he wasnt wearing the suit. And the people in the Hospital will not claim out loud that "an invisible man attacked them" - they'll just be in shock and their claims will be dismissed as Cecilia's claims were.

Answer (score 3):

1. The police doesn't know that there's another suit (and that Cecilia know how to use it)
2. The detective is a close friend of Cecilia
3. CCTV video is an evidence which is hard to dispute
4. Cecilia is considered a victim and will continue to be treated as a victim by the police
5. Smiling isn't an evidence of not being suicidal

Comment: +1. In regard to your last line: put or wear? In the last scene, the invisible suit was in her handbag.

Comment: @C.F.G I'll remove my last comment

Answer (score 0):

Because someone who previosuly faked his own death but later turn out to be alive have around zero credibility. And why he wouldn't commit suicide? Police knew he is somehow capable of it (because that's how he "died" previosuly).

People see what they want to see and Adrian is not the most loveable person for the officers to be willing to doubt his obvious, clearly seen suicide. Also does the CCTV show that he is looking smug and satisfied?

Comment: Adrian claimed that he was a victim too